# How to know what C++ Builder needed to open existing project

Tags: version, project, c++builder

I've got an existing project written long ago and it seems that the project was done in C++ Builder - it has *.dfm, *cbproj files.

But I cannot open it in C++ Builder 6 because there is no *.bpr,*.bpg or *.bpk files.

If I create new project and import there all existing *.cpp files then Borland is saying about multiple errors like "ControlBar->CornerEdge property does not exist" and so on.

My guess is that it is made in some very old Builder (older than 6.0) but how can I know what exactly Builder is needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

cbproj files are evidence of a newer version, definitely not C++Builder 6 or older.

You can check the version within the cbproj file, the first lines include a `ProjectVersion` field that will tell you more or less what version was used. For instance:

- C++Builder XE5: `15.3`.
- C++Builder 2010: `12.0`.
- C++Builder 2007: doesn't have this property.

I don't have any other version here installed to check, but you can probably get an idea with this values.

Comment: The `TControlBar::CornerEdge` property was introduced sometime around C++Builder 2007/2009.